# how to get diff between subsequent rows without lag

Tags: sql, postgresql, lag

I have

```
id value
1 12
1 15
1 17
1 22
1 22
1 23
```

And I need like this

```
id  value
1 --
1 3
1 2
1 5
1 0
1 1
```

Could you tell me, how to achive this?

Comment: Isn't id increasing?

Comment: What's wrong with using `lag()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
select id, 
      value-max(value) over(order by id rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) as value
from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `lag()`, which I'm guessing is per `id` and based on the ordering of `value`:

```
select t.*,
       (value - lag(value) over (partition by id order by value)) as diff
from t
order by value;
```

That said, your sample data has exact duplicates.  That is unusual in a SQL table.